# Conditional statement ENVI

Tags: gdal, envi, conditional, idl, if-statement

I am trying to do conditional statement in ENVI to calculate multiband image:

```
result = (b1)^2 - (b2)^2
if (b1 eq 0) or (b2 eq 0)
result * 0
else
result * (result gt 0.0)
```

Is there a way to combine the statements in Band Math? Or I have to write in IDL?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but this expression would work using ENVI Band Math:

```
(b1^2 - b2^2) * ((b1 NE 0) AND (b2 NE 0))
```

HTH.